# Line break before a special character

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-breaks

I use a template webpage, and supplier does not give permission to change most thing in system. But I can reach HTML and CSS of the web, Is it possible to put a line break before "(" character. Is CSS or HTML enough or do I need another coding?

I have HTML like; (Link and Title of that link comming from inline code that i cannot reach or change) Moreover, This HTML code generated automatically from CMS of website, therefore it cannot be update like adding break code before "(". In otherwords, it will not shown in website HTML, it recalled from somewhere else that i cannot update. Therefore I need a coding that recognize "(" char. and put break before it. because text of it not always same length.

```
 <div class="showcaseTitle">
    <a href="tour_package_ID_0011.html">
        Tour Package (129€)         </a>
</div>
```

I have CSS like;

```
.showcaseTitle {
height: 32px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

It shows on main page of website single line  but i need to put the price on second line like below

> Tour Package
>   (129€)

How can i solve this problem ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT :**

As mentioned in the comments, you can't change the *HTML* so thx to [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930419/css-break-before-a-special-character#comment-40593497) here is a JS function that replaces all "`(`" characters by "`<br>(`" therefore you will have a line break before the "(" character.

```js
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('showcaseTitle')[0].innerHTML;

txt = txt.replace(/\(/g, '<br>(');

document.getElementsByClassName('showcaseTitle')[0].innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<div class="showcaseTitle">
    <a href="tour_package_ID_0011.html">
        Tour Package (129€)         </a>
</div>
```

---

**Original answer :**

As you can change the HTML markup, the simplest would be to add a line break in the *HTML* with the [line break tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) (`<br/>`) :

```
<div class="showcaseTitle">
    <a href="tour_package_ID_0011.html">
        Tour Package
        <br/> <!-- this line ! -->
        (129€)
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You were faster than me, +1

Comment: RP for free. Can't understand someone doesn't know `<br>` normal tag.

Comment: But it is not solve my issue. I cannot put <br/> in HTML editing because packages added from admin page of website and it generate this HTML code of that div automatically. I will not shown on main page's HTML. I need to put <br/> before "(" character in that div after that automatic adding..

Comment: @MichaelAdam ah, so you can't change the HTML (you mentioned you could in the question). Maybe there is a CSS solution for this. Is the sentence "Tour package" always the same or does it change?

Comment: @MichaelAdam: In that case I think you would need JavaScript (or one of its many libraries)

Comment: I update question more breifly. It is not a simple break situation like some comments mention. I flag this answer as not correct one. 

@web-tiki length is changing for every item. Therefore it needs to recognize "(" char. Maybe a CSS soln. is found but my skills not enough.

Comment: @Harry do you know which libraries are that?

Comment: @MichaelAdam: Just vanilla JS would be enough. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/50dyfhkg/) is a very base example of how it can be done, but ofcourse in real world your code would have to handle more complex cases than just a straight-forward replace.

Comment: @MichaelAdam ok I can't think of a CSS solution for this then. As Harry mentioned, you will need to use JS with probably a regex to identify the "(" character.

Comment: @MichaelAdam: Just to elaborate what I meant by complex cases. Sometimes you may have inputs with two `((` in which case this would introduce two line breaks. I am using `innerHTML`, so the HTML tag contents would also go into the variable and in the tag there could be cases where you are passing a value within braces `onclick`. All those have to be handled extra otherwise it will result in too many breaks.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. It is solved my problem.